# OpenJDK:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints

Tags: algorithm, ssl, certificate, jetty, java

My web service in **jetty** with **OpenJDK1.8.0** try to establish an HTTPS connection to an Microsoft server , and I got this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
......
```

Trust Microsoft server's certificate looks fine:

- Public Key:          **RSA (2048 Bits)**
- Signature Algorithm: **sha256RSA**
- Signature hash algorithm:    **sha256**
  None algorathm matched the `jre_path/lib/security/java.security` **disableAlgorithm**:

  jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024
  jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768

I checked TLS Cipher Suite support both in jetty and Microsoft , everything look fine:

- TLS1_1:    **ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA**
- TLS1_2:    **ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384**
- TLS1:      **ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA**

**My question:**

1. What caused "Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints" exception?
2. As far as I know,OpenJDK supports unlimited strength crypto without the need for additional policy files.Is anythong I omitted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Caused by the **signature algorithm** in the certificate used in Windows server adopted an alogrithm in the future **TLSv1.3** standard, so the OpenJDK throwen this exception.